# Creating BufferedImage with width, height and bit depth

Tags: java

I would like to create a **BufferedImage** with certin width, height (800x600) and bit depth of 24 and I would like image background to be transparent.

How do I do that?

Thanking you.

Comment: Please do a smidgen of research before crying out for help, googling the statement "how to make a transparent buffered image" yields about 100,000 results... try something before giving up.

Comment: This is a standard Java class. Refer to the documentation online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the constructor and pass a suitable format parameter:

```
new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_?);
```

where TYPE_? is on of the constants that define a format with alpha channel, like TYPE_INT_ARGB.

Edit: Straight from BufferedImage

```
/**
 * Represents an image with 8-bit RGBA color components packed into
 * integer pixels.  The image has a <code>DirectColorModel</code>
 * with alpha. The color data in this image is considered not to be
 * premultiplied with alpha.  When this type is used as the
 * <code>imageType</code> argument to a <code>BufferedImage</code>
 * constructor, the created image is consistent with images
 * created in the JDK1.1 and earlier releases.
 */
public static final int TYPE_INT_ARGB = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks @Durandal ... but where I define the bit depth?

Comment: @user836026 Take a look at the javadoc. The bit depth is part of the format constants, e.g. each constant comes with a specific bit depth.

Answer (score 1):

These are the options you have with BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage(ColorModel cm, WritableRaster raster, boolean isRasterPremultiplied, Hashtable<?,?> properties) 

BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType) 

BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType, IndexColorModel cm)
```